# Group by a set of columns and check if a value corresponding to another column exists in Teradata/SQL

Tags: sql, teradata

Input:

[image]

I need to group by `(mnth_end_d, id, name)` and check if there is a value for `debt_calc` corresponding to when `period_rank = 'T'`. And if there's a value, you create this new column `debt_exists` and populate it with `TRUE` or `FALSE` as in the output table below. Any tips on how to do that in Teradata without using any joins (perhaps using partition over)?

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your requirement translates into a *conditional aggregation* in SQL:

```
       -- if there is a value for debt_calc corresponding to when period_rank = 'T'
max(case when period_rank = 'T' and debt_calc is not null 
         then 'TRUE'   -- populate it with TRUE or FALSE 
         else 'FALSE'
    end) 
over (partition by mnth_end_d, id, name) as debt_exists
```